# which dll or namespace of ASP.net 4 (MVC5) should not be present in ASP.5 (MVC6) after migration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I understood from post available at below link

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

that ASP.Net 5 no longer required to have system.web.dll, what are the other namespace it should not have.

My MVC 5 project references system.web.extension.dll perticulary *JavaScriptSerializer* Class, i am not sure if should be using that or if there is any other alternative to it.

there are other namespaces also start with system.web as below should that also be avoided

```
 using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
    using System.Web.OData;
    using System.Web.OData.Routing;
```

is it that only system.web.dll should not be used in ASP.net 5 MVC 6 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe anything beginning `system.web.*` shouldn't be there and has been replaced with something within `Microsoft.AspNet`.

I'm not sure how you are planning on doing the migration but the article [Migrating From ASP.NET MVC 5 to MVC 6](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfrommvc5.html) on docs.asp.net covers the process pretty well.

Essentially it advises starting with a blank MVC 6 / Asp.Net.Core 1 (the new name for Asp.Net 5) project and porting the content over.

That way you can lean on the compiler to tell you things that aren't available. A lot of what can / can't will depend on wether its Framework 4.6 or .NET Core 1.0 (prevously .NET Core 5).

As for *JavaScriptSerializer* I believe the recomended alternative is [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Depending what you use it for there is also now [JsonOutputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/39fe063aeec41bec2d93eaea3cfcc66c2b8c493d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Formatters/JsonOutputFormatter.cs) and [JsonInputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/39fe063aeec41bec2d93eaea3cfcc66c2b8c493d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Formatters/JsonInputFormatter.cs)

I haven't been through the full process yet, but I strongly suspect moving to Framework 4.6 will be the easier destination :-)

Comment: mine is pretty big project with lots of file and changes.

Comment: TBH, whilst I’m excited about all the new features and changes, I'm in no rush to get my teams to migrate over to it. Will definitely give this one time to bed in and let others go through the migration pain first. :-) My gut says this is going to be a pretty hard migration.

Comment: yes..its pretty hard....our project is in MVC and we wanted self hosting for out web application .team found that its not possible without converting to MVC6 and asp.net 5..thats why its converted. do you have any idea if System.Web.OData  namespace also changed to microsoft.aspnet.*..i donloaded that package and found that its there is still system.web.odata.dll in that package(Microsoft.AspNet.OData).

Comment: anyway, if i am done successfully i will update my details. it will be useful to your project ;)